# trying to call function in child component fails

Tags: reactjs

I have two React components, Parent and Child, each is separate module in its own file. I'm using Redux, so both are "export default compose"...

In the Parent's constructor:

```
this.myChild = React.createRef();
```

In the Parent's render:

```
<Child ref={this.myChild} />
```

Child has method defined:

```
getAlert() {
//do something
}
```

I'm trying to call in one of Parent's method:

```
this.myChild.current.getAlert();
```

But I get:

```
this.myChild.current.getAlert() is not a function.
```

I verified that this.myChild.current is not null.

What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot use `refs` to call function inside child element, in general, refs are considered bad practice. What is `getAlert` supposed to do ?

Comment: I just put the name as a sample. In reality it will clear a textbox by clearing the state value. I’ve seen an example of being able to call a function working somewhere (I’ll share the url in a while), but they were simple react components in the same file.

Comment: here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/kw5mn93wmr) i was talking about. It's calling a function in the child

Answer (score 0):

Refs are used to access the DOM, not the React component (which is a JS class). As per [the official docs on refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> In the typical React dataflow, props are the only way that parent components interact with their children. To modify a child, you re-render it with new props.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively. For example, instead of exposing open() and close() methods on a Dialog component, pass an isOpen prop to it.

Comment: I thought refs were a good idea for simple ui related tasks, no? here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/kw5mn93wmr) to a project where it is calling the child's function from the parent. how is this working?